# How to count how many rows match a criteria within a defined range of rows following an initial criteria?

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have some data that looks a bit like this

```
library(dplyr)

employee <- employee <- c('John','Dave','Paul','Ringo','George','Tom','Jim','Harry','Jamie','Adrian')
quality <- c('good', 'bad')
x = runif(4000,0,100)
y = runif(4000,0,100)
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, quality, x, y)
```

I want to set a first criteria (i.e, any row where the employee = 'George' and the quality = 'good') and then count how many rows within a certain range of that criteria (lets say five rows) match a second criteria (i.e, any row where the employee = 'Jim' and the x = >50). How could I go about doing that in R?

Hopefully that was clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question, but wouldn't the two criteria you mentioned in your example be mutually exclusive (employee being Jim, employee being George)?

Comment: Yes, they aren't supposed to be matching criteria. I just want to count if that second criteria is found in n rows following the first one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for the criteria you mentioned in your question.

As an edit to what you asked for in the comment, I would wrap it up in a function in order to apply it to all levels of your employee variable

```
 criterion_range <- function(n, group) {
  # n: the number of rows after the first criterion
  # group: the employee you want to include in the first criterion
  n = n

  # index for the first criterion:
  ind1 <- which(employ.data$employee == group & employ.data$quality == 
                  "bad")

  if(length(ind1) > 0) {

  # index for all the next n rows following and n rows preceding rows with 
  # criterion 1:
  ind_n <- c(t(sapply(-n:n, function(x) {ind1 + x})))

  # to make sure that the index does not go beyond the rows in the sample:
  ind_n <- ind_n[ind_n <= nrow(employ.data) & ind_n > 0]

  # index of the rows that fall within that range of ind_n and match a second  
  # criterion
  ind2 <- which(employ.data[ind_n,"employee"] == "Jim" & 
                  employ.data[ind_n,"x"] > 60)

  return(nrow(employ.data[ind2,]))
  }
}

# this will give run the function for each employee in your df, you can 
# specify n here
unlist(sapply(levels(employ.data$employee), criterion_range, n = 3))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is ideal! One further question if it's not too onerous: is there a way to do it by group? I.e instead of choosing specifically  "George" in the first criterion you do it by each one in the employee group?

Comment: I have made an edit to the code, so that it can run through each in the employee group. Let me know if something is unclear

Comment: This is again very useful, thank you. Is the result at the end (the unlist) showing the count from the perspective the first criterion or the second criterion? The thing I'm looking for is to get the count for the first criterion, eg: how many times is each George/Jim etc's name followed by whatever is defined in the second criterion. I'm not really concerned with counting it from the perspective of the second (i.e, this is how often that employee's name follows the first criterion)

Comment: In the code above, the second criterion is fixed  and in the first criterion the employee name varies with each iteration.

Comment: Sorry I don't think my question was clearly worded. Is the final 'unlist(sapply(levels(employ.data$employee), criterion_range, n = 3))' are the names that show up in the final cumulative count from the perspective of criterion 1 or 2?

Comment: it shows how many times each name is followed or preceded by whatever is defined in the second criterion.

Comment: so the perspective of criterion 1

Comment: Thank you! And thank you again for all the help, incredibly kind.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry one more question, you don't have to answer if you don't want to as I've already taken up plenty of your time: Is there a way to automatically match up names between criterion 1 and 2? E.g criterion 1 is the group of employee name and quality="bad" and criterion 2 is how often quality="bad" appears within n rows and the same employee name matches the name it appears within n rows of (the group specified in criterion 1)? eg: it would count how many times "George" appears within n of "George", how many times "Jim" appears within n of "Jim", etc and so on for the rest of the group.

Comment: Apologies again if I worded that poorly.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the number of rows you want to look at preceding and following hits for the first criteria by adjusting values for `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`.

```
library(dplyr)

# Generate employee data
employee <- c('John','Dave','Paul','Ringo','George','Tom','Jim','Harry','Jamie','Adrian')
quality <- c('good', 'bad')
x = runif(4000,0,100)
y = runif(4000,0,100)
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, quality, x, y)

# Extract row numbers that satisfy criteria 1
criteria1 <- which(employ.data$employee == "George" & employ.data$quality == "good")

# Set lower bounds for rows that satisfy criteria 1
lower_bound <- 5

lower <- criteria1 - lower_bound
lower <- ifelse(lower <= 0, 1, lower)

# Ser upper bounds for rows that satisfy criteria 1
upper_bound <- 5

upper <- criteria1 + upper_bound
upper <- ifelse(upper > 4000, 4000, upper)

# Create a list that contains the appropriate range for each row that satisfies criteria 1
range <- rbind(lower, upper)

# Combine all ranges to form a vector of unique row numbers
rows <- unique(unlist(apply(range, 2, function(r) r[1]:r[2])))

# Find how many rows in the extended range satisfy criteria 2
criteria2 <- nrow(employ.data[rows,][employ.data[rows,]$employee == "Jim" & employ.data[rows,]$x >= 50,])

print(criteria2)
```